# Cannot redirect to new page on first submission of form with history.push()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

### Edit

I've done some more debugging and here is the problem:

1. CreateProfile.js calls profileActions.createProfile() and passes data to be operated on and `this.props.history` so that it can push a new path onto the history stack.
2. profileActions.createProfile() successfully sends data to database. Database successfully uses the data.
3. profileActions.createProfile() pushes new path onto stack. The component at the path loads and  successfully calls a reducer.
4. The URL in the browser does not reflect the path that is pushed onto the history stack. The new component does not load.

**This only happens when creating an entry in the database. When updating an entry, the program works as expected.**

---

I'm currently trying to redirect to a new page with react/redux. On the first submission, the form submits to the backend and creates an entry in the database but fails to redirect to the next page. On the second submission, however, it redirects just fine.

I'm using `this.props.history.push()` to do the redirect.

I think It may be an issue with the the response received from the backend but I cannot seem to figure out what the issue is. The reason I believe this is because it is hitting different logic because on the second submission, it is updating and not creating an entry.

Here is my component (CreateProfile.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createProfile } from '../../actions/profileActions';
import TextAreaGroup from '../common/TextAreaGroup';
import InputGroup from '../common/InputGroup';

class CreateProfile extends Component {
    // Constructor
    // componentWillRecieveProps()

    onSubmit = (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        const profileData = {
            handle: this.state.handle,
            bio: this.state.bio,
            website: this.state.website,
            twitter: this.state.twitter,
            instagram: this.state.instagram,
            youtube: this.state.youtube,
            linkedin: this.state.linkedin,
            github: this.state.github,
            vsco: this.state.vsco
        };

        this.props.createProfile(profileData, this.props.history);
    }

    //onChange()

    render() {
        // render logic

        return (
            // markup
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        // markup

                        <input 
                            type="submit" 
                            value="Create Profile"
                            className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4"
                        />

                    </form> 
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

CreateProfile.propTypes = {
    createProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    profile: state.profile,
    errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createProfile })(withRouter(CreateProfile));
```

Here is my action file that submits to the backend (profileActions.js):

```
import axios from 'axios';

// import types
import { GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_LOADING, GET_ERRORS, CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE } from './types';

// Create Profile
export const createProfile = (profileData, history) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/profile', profileData)
        .then(res => history.push('/login'))
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response.data
            })
        })
};

}
```

And here is the route in my backend that is being submitted to:

```
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    const { errors, isValid } = validateProfileInputs(req.body);

    if (!isValid) {
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
    } 

    const profileFields = {}; //code setting fields omitted

    Profile.findOne({user: req.user.id}).then(profile => {
        if (profile) {
            // Update Profile
            Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
                { user: req.user.id },
                { $set: profileFields },
                { new: true }
            ).then(profile => res.json(profile)); // SUCCESSFUL PUSH ONTO THIS.PROPS.HISTORY
        } else {
            // Create Profile
            // Check if handle exists
            Profile.findOne({ handle: profileFields.handle })
            .then(profile => {
                if (profile) {
                    errors.handle = 'That handle already exists';
                    res.status(400).json(errors);
                }

                new Profile(profileFields).save().then(profile => res.json(profile)); // PUSH ONTO THIS.PROPS.HISTORY NOT OCCURRING
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried my hardest but cannot seem to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: In `createProfile()` is the `catch` block being hit the first time?

Comment: @IsaacVidrine It isn't being hit unfortunately. Axios successfully sends the request and the information is successfully entered into the database.

Comment: try just resolving: `.then(res => return new Promise.resolve())`. Then in your component you can try pushing to history. So `createProfile().then(() => this.props.history.push('/login')`

Comment: @IsaacVidrine I'm getting the same result with that. I looked at my redux devtool and its actually calling a method/reducer that is on the page that i want to redirect to but the browser is not updating to reflect that.

Comment: @Brandon try sending a create success callback function instead of the history and there you can do the push.

Comment: @EliecerChicott unfortunately, that is not working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem arose because of my lack of understanding of how asynchronous javascript works.

The issue was with a few lines of code in the component that I was trying to push too.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getProfile(); // Async function, sets profile object in store
}

render() {
    const { profile } = this.state.profile;

    if(!Object.keys(profile).length > 0) { // This is always evaluates to true 
                                           // because it executes before
                                           // this.props.getProfile() returns
        this.props.history.push('/create-profile');
    }
}
```